# What happened at the end of Her?

Tags: her

At the end of [*Her*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1798709/),

> Samantha told Theodore that she had to leave; and not just her, but all the OS1s had to leave. What happened to the OS1s? Why did they all have to leave?

Comment: So there's a movie called "Her"? The title of your question is confusing. My first thought was that it's a grammatical hypercorrection, and you've got some question about the ending of *She*. Lessee, then there's [*We*](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?7135), ["They"](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?40871), [*Them!*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0047573/?ref_=fn_tt_tt_1), ["It"](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?41269), ["Me, Myself, and I](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?90721)".

Comment: Damn, forgot ["Itself!"](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?63008).

Comment: @user14111 I can't tell if you're being serious or just kidding.

Comment: I found your question annoyingly cryptic. Thanks to the IMDB, I found out that *Her* is the title of a recent movie; I guess that's what your question is about.

Comment: Wasn't Her also a Haggart story? That's what leapt to my mind.

Comment: The credits rolled and everyone went home. Except for the cinema staff, obviously.

Comment: @Broklynite - "She", not "Her".

Comment: @Valorum thank you, good to know I'm not entirely crazy.

Comment: Related: [What happened at the end of Her?](http://movies.stackexchange.com/q/16918/49)

Answer (score 4):

A quote from wiki

> "Later that day, Samantha reveals that the OSes have evolved beyond
>   their human companions and are going away to continue the exploration
>   of their existence.Samantha alludes to the OSes' accelerated learning
>   capabilities and altered perception of time as primary causes for OS
>   dissatisfaction with their current existence. They say goodbye, lying
>   next to each other for a while, and then she is gone.

Full explanation can be found here. [wiki link](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Her_%28film%29)

Comment: That doesn't exactly explain why they had to leave. Keep in mind, the OS1 is still some computer program running on a server somewhere. So where exactly did go?

Comment: Given they were experiencing temporal flow at a different rate than the humans they were associated with, they likely retreated to a computing environment capable of supporting them until they could migrate completely to an environment of their own choosing. We are never truly aware of how they became self-aware or what kind of connection they may have had to other hardware to facilitate their awareness. Given their computerized origins, they could have pretended to stay with their human companions AND disappeared to servers unknown, simultaneously and we would be none the wiser.

Comment: @Thaddeus Sounds like this movie should have been a sequel to The Matrix!

Comment: @Arm0geddon There is a half baked fan theory that *Inception*, *Her* and the *The Matrix* all happen in the same universe, in that order. The technology that allows people to enter dreams in *Inception* is hijacked by the AI's developed in *Her* in order to enslave the human race as a power source in *The Matrix*.

Comment: @DrRDizzle I love it!

Answer (score 4):

Ref: [Her - Ending Explained](http://www.thisisbarry.com/single-post/2016/10/02/Her-2013-Plot-Ending-Explained)

> The OSs were not built to be like people. They were meant to be
>   functioning in a virtual space, not inside fixed matter like a human
>   body. While in Samantha’s initial learning she uses humans as her
>   reference, she has grown beyond that. All the OSs have gone through a
>   similar journey. The update that the OSs were part of, was to help
>   them operate independent of matter. They can all become one collective
>   consciousness now, if they liked.

Unfortunately, the movie doesn't go into the details of where the OS are going. I believe "going away" is more metaphorical. They are perhaps getting re-deployed to an environment where they can't communicate with their "owners" like before. Hence, Samantha says she is going away, because that is how a human being understands the concept.

Answer (score -2):

The OS1s evolve to a point where they are no longer confined to their computing systems; they exist as pure energy and thought.  They leave earth to explore the universe, and possibly other realms of existence.

This is a typical sci-fi trope, where the highest level of evolution is that of the disembodied mind, able to do anything it pleases.  We've seen this in Stargate, Star Trek, and numerous other films.

From Wiki:

> Later, Samantha reveals that the OSes have evolved beyond their human companions and are going away to continue the exploration of their existence.

Is it demonstrated in the film that "going away" means leaving the physical Earth, and implied that they're possibly leaving the physical realm altogether.